# HttpInterceptor retry in Angular 4.3

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to write my first code to catch 401 errors using HttpInterceptor.  What I want to do is depending on a condition create a new auth token and then retry with that.  But currently my code makes the retry, but it does it before the new auth token has been created. Here is my code :

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {

    return next.handle(request).catch(error => {

        if (error.status === 401) {

            console.log('401 error');

            //check for valid refresh token
            let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            this._refreshTokenService.getRefreshToken(refreshToken).subscribe(
                refreshToken => {
                    if (refreshToken != null) {

                        console.log('valid refresh token')

                        //if valid refresh token, relogin and create new auth token 
                        console.log(localStorage.getItem('auth_token'));

                        this._userService.logout();

                        let email = localStorage.getItem('profile_email');

                        this._userService.autoLogin(email)
                            .subscribe(
                            result => {
                                if (result) {
                                    console.log('new auth token created');

                                    let auth_token = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');

                                    //retry
                                    request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${auth_token}`) });
                                }
                            });


                    }
                    else {
                        console.log('invalid refresh token');
                    }
                });
            return next.handle(request);
        }
        else {
            console.log(error.status);
        }
    });
}
```

I am still getting familiar with Typescript syntax, I think I need to make the retry only occur after the new token has been created, but I am not sure of the exact syntax in this case.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot reply in the comments.
I guess this is all about chaining Observable.

Basically everything you call before your last `return next.handle(request);` gets processed before angular make your http call. 
Except that everything inside `this._refreshTokenService.getRefreshToken(refreshToken).subsribe()` will be processed asynchronously.

You should chain your Observable like this :

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle(request).catch(error => {
        return this._refreshTokenService.getRefreshToken(refreshToken).subscribe(
            refreshToken => {
                return next.handle(request);
            }
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  I tried to move the 'return next.handle(request)' line  so that it is directly after the clone line, but this gives me syntax error 'Type void is not assignable to type ObservableInput<any>'. I guess I need to have the return line where I have it in my original post, but how do I prevent it being run before the rest of the code has finished running?

Comment: Also I tried your example and it gives error 'Type Subscription is not assignable to type ObservableInput<any>'. This is probably not that difficult to solve, but the syntax is hard to get my head around :)

Comment: Pretty sure this is because he's subscribing to the value. Once you subscribe you basically break the chain, an interceptor expects an observable to return.  instead of subscribe try flatMap